# sed regular expressions address ranges

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a txt file that looks something like this

```
-----------------------------------
           RUNNING PROCESSES
-----------------------------------

ftpd
kswapd
init
etc..

---------------------------------
          HOSTNAME
--------------------------------
```

mypc.local.com

With sed I want to just get one section of this file.  So just the RUNNING PROCESSES section, however I seem to be failing to get my regexp right to do so.

I got this far

```
sed -n '/^-./,/RUNNING PROCESSES/, /[[:space::]]/p' linux.txt | more
```

however it keeps complaining about

-e expression #1, char 26: unknown commmand `,'

Can anybody help??

Comment: You've got three patterns which is not a sed address. It is complaining about the second `,` and I can't figure what your `p` directive is trying to do.

Comment: `p` is supposed to print the matched pattern, because printing is disabled by `-n`.

Comment: do you want the "header" (--- RUNNING PROCESSES ---) included in the output, or only the processes (ftps, kswpd, init, etc.)?

Comment: Including the header, but not the next header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
sed -n '/RUNNING PROCESSES/,/HOSTNAME/p' linux.txt | 
  sed -e '/^[- ]/d' -e '/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably prefer to use `awk` for that:

```
awk '/RUNNING PROCESSES/ {s=2}
     /^---/              {s=s-1}
                         {if(s>0){print}}' linux.txt
```

That `awk` will give you:

```
           RUNNING PROCESSES
-----------------------------------

ftpd
kswapd
init
etc..
```

You can then pipe that through `sed '/^$/d'` to filter out the blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variable of the answer accepted, but not extra call to another sed process

```
sed -n '/RUNNING PROCESSES/,/HOSTNAME/{s/RUNN.*\|HOSTNAME//;s/--*//;/^$/!p}' file
```